# Data binding to observable in metro style app with javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I'm having problems with databinding in a metro javascript app on Windows 8.

on **Build xxxx **

I create value I want to bind to

```
var someValue = WinJS.Binding.as({ primitive : 1 });
```

I've actually put this in global scope to rule things out

Then just set a simple callback to update this value every 5s

```
setInterval(function () { someValue. primitive++ }, 5000);
WinJS.Binding.processAll();
```

this is in the ready function of the page js file

Then in the HTML file just a simple h1 tag

```
<h1 data-win-bind="innerText : someValue.primitive">Test</h1>
```

When this page runs it does databind initially - so the h1 tag shows 1 but never shows anything else.  The callback does get hit and at any point I can inspect the someValue and it looks right.  I've tried using setProperty and updateProperty on the someValue object but it doesn't make any difference.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer yet, but just wanted to mention, are you sure you are suppose to post anything about the build on public forum? Isn't there an NDA associated with it?

Comment: No idea.  Thanks though. this gets it working: HTML: `<h1 data-win-bind="innerText : primitive">Test</h1>` js: `WinJS.Binding.processAll(document.body, someValue);`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with global.  I tried a few other things and it appears that you can't data bind to an object that has global scope.

```
<h1 data-win-bind="innerText : variable">Test</h1>
```

the 'variable' cannot be in global is if the variable you're binding to has global scope it just breaks.

but if you just namespace is say variable.variable then it works - but because it's been namespaced you then have to pass in this as a data context.

WinJS.Binding.processAll(document.body, variable)

My problem was I had a ViewModel.Login, ViewModel.Basket object and I just wanted to bind ViewModel and then have relevant sections bind to the bits they need.

// ViewModel.Test.test.guidePrice = "£3.00";

works
    `<h1 data-win-bind="innerText : test.guidePrice">Test</h1>`
    `WinJS.Binding.processAll(document.getElementById('basketPrice'),ViewModel.Test);`

doesn't work
    `<h1 data-win-bind="innerText : Test.test.guidePrice">Test</h1>`
    `WinJS.Binding.processAll(document.getElementById('basketPrice'),ViewModel);`

Hope this helps anyone with the same/similar problems!